# Emails from my domain goest to spam - Split IP and suspicious server name

Tags: dns, email, spam, vps

I have an issue with my VPS and Mails on OVH.

I ordered a VPS and domain name for it. In Cpanel, I created a new user, added my domain name and some emails account. Website works fine and the same for mails (Can send et receive emails). My only issue with emails is Spam Assasin. All mails sended from my domain name goes to spam folder everywhere (Hotmail, Gmail etc).

This is “error” message:

> 0.0 CK_HELO_DYNAMIC_SPLIT_IP Relay HELO’d using suspicious hostname* (Split IP)

I don’t know if i configurated correctly my DNS.

This is my configuration:

```
NS: dns16.ovh.net.
NS: ns16.ovh.net.
MX: vpsXXXX.ovh.net
A: My VPS IP
AAAA: My VPS IPV6
SPF: "v=spf1 a mx mx:vpsXXXXX.ovh.net ip4:51.XXX.XXX.XXX ip6:XXXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:0:0:0:53ca ~all"
DMKEY: v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=[My Key];
```

Answer (score 1):

It left a PTR record in your DNS settings regarding your HELO.

You should have a PTR record for your HELO address hostname for each IPs.

Then you should try to fix better your spf record like add + and the IPs where you will be sending.

And after all the routing config you still will need to generate something called reputation if is it a new ip. You can always ask for automatic reputation pass if you qualify, like in Microsoft (More info: [Outlook Protection](https://sendersupport.olc.protection.outlook.com/pm/))